# Php Preparement statements echo result from query

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

Just for you all to know, im starting to learn PDO so dont get mad at me :)

When i was using mysqli i would do this get the result from a query and echo something:

```
$query2= "SELECT acess FROM statistic WHERE id_page IN(SELECT id FROM page WHERE title='".$registos1['title']."')";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($ligaBD,$query2);
        $registos2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

        if($registos2['acess']==0){
            echo '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>...</title></head><body>This page is private.</body></html>';exit;
```

And now im trying to do it on PDO but im not shure if it is like is:

```
$sql = "SELECT acess FROM statistic WHERE id_page IN(SELECT id FROM page WHERE title=?)";
        $stm = $ligaBD->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute(array($acess));
        $stm->fetchColumn();

        if(($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
            echo '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Easy Page Builder</title></head><body>This page is private.</body></html>';exit;
        }
```

This `if($registos2['acess']==0){` does the same thing as this `if(($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){` ?

What is the value returned from fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ? I have read that is boolean but im not shure if this is even the proper code to use to get the result from the query like i was doing in the past when using mysqli.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. it doesn't. You've missed one step in your PDO code. You fetch a row, but then don't look at what you fetched. It should be more like:

```
    $stm->execute(array($acess));
    $row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($row['access'] == 0) {
       ...
    }
```

As your code is written, you fetch a row result, but use that row result in a basic if(). If data was retrieved, $row will be some non-empty data, and PHP casts it to boolean TRUE, meaning you get the 'access denied' message. This will happen even if the actual results of the query say "access granted" because you're not looking at the resulting data from the query, you're just testing if ANY data was returned AT ALL.

Comment: Got "Undefined index: access " on the if line. Did exactly as you suggested, what can it be?

Comment: probably a typo. I see you've got `acess` in your code, with one `c`.

Comment: Yes, thats it! Thanks alot, you made my day (:

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the data from the access column, `fetchColumn()` is enough.

```
/* The $columnIndex is the zero-based index of the `access` column */

$sql = "SELECT acess FROM statistic WHERE id_page IN(SELECT id FROM page WHERE title=?)";
$stm = $ligaBD->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($acess));
$result = $stm->fetchColumn($columnIndex);

if($resut === 0){
        echo '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Easy Page Builder</title></head><body>This page is private.</body></html>';exit;
}
```

Remember `$result` can be `FALSE` if no row returned or `0` if the column `access` has this value. Therefore you must compare with the `===` operator.

Comment: What is the value of the $columIndex variable? Or i just say that $columIndex=0 ?

Comment: It depends on the order of your result table. For example if your result table has `id`, `access` and `foo` column in that order, the `$columnIndex` should be `1`.